# jQuery on click doesn't work at firefox no errors in console

Tags: jquery, firefox, click

latest Firefox at Mac Os Siera.
Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.tabs-nav .col3').on('click', function(event){
alert('aaa');
});
});
```

Comment: Have you read http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post some of your HTML? Also your function doesn't require an argument (event) in this situation.  And if your col3 class is nested inside your tabs-nav class, consider using

```
$('.tabs-nav > .col3').on('click', function() {...
```

Comment: I'd also advise against using (document).ready unless you have events that you want to fire immediately when the page is loaded.  For this case, you can get rid of it and simple is the on(click) event